# Does Python need to know the definition of passed, but unused object?

Tags: python

A, B, C and X are classes in different modules.
I want to pass an object of class X the following way: A->B->C

Is it necessary then to inculde class X in B, or it can pass a class X object without knowing its definition? (I don't need to use its methods or anything, just return with the object)

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: Duck Typing means that you only need to import the class if you're making one.

Comment: @arshajii: to be fair, sometimes "just trying it" can give the wrong answer -- lots of people come to the wrong conclusion about how `is` works by trying `(2==3) is False` and `4 is 4`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not.

About the only time you have to `from some_module import some_object` is when you are going to create instances of `some_object`, or you want to catch exceptions from `some_module`.  If you have instances of `some_object` being passed in you use it normally (read, write, or call various attributes, etc.).